# Fill between lines on a chart

Tags: google-visualization

I have been using Google visualisation API's annotated timeline graph to display various annotated lines. However, I have been struggling to colour between an upper and lower limit line on the chart to indicate an acceptable range of actual values.

I was able to get it right using the Image chart library - heres a link showing what I am trying for below, but the problem with this is the data limitation google imposes of 2000 records.

chm=b,00FF0066,0,2,0 from the link below is what colors the area between line 0 and 2 green.

> http://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=440x220&cht=lxy&chco=3072F3,FF0000,FF9900&chds=0,30,0,100,0,30,6,15,0,30,0,30&chd=t:-1|13.05,13.05,13.05,13.05,13.05,13.05,13.05,13.05,13.05,13.05,13.05,13.05|-1|6.108,7.183,6.964,8.063,8.05,6.96,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1|-1|7.252,7.252,7.252,7.252,7.252,7.252,7.252,7.252,7.252,7.252,7.252,7.252&chdl=LowerLimit|Value|UpperLimit&chdlp=b&chls=2|1|1&chma=0,5,5,25&chtt=Limited+Range+Graph&chm=b,00FF0066,0,2,0&chf=c,s,ff000033|bg,s,efefef

I have tried the Visualisation API's image chart as well, but it just ignores the *chm* option I used in the above snippet.

Any idea's how to get around the visualisation limitation more than welcome, I have also tried looking around for this capability in other API's, but google only seems to think this is possible in excel, near as I can tell.

Answer (score 1):

The annotated timeline (and in fact the entire non-Image chart visualization implementation) doesn't support coloring between 2 lines. There currently really isn't anything that lets you do this: the closest Highcharts comes to is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/PXfeP/), so see if that works for you.